# Javascript Slideshow Images Loading Over HTML Element

Tags: javascript, css, element, slideshow

I have a page in which I have a fixed footer that scrolls with the page, however on the page there is a Javascript slideshow, as the slideshow loads in a new image, it loads it over the fixed footer.

The page in question is this one: http://mysterybox.co/signalnoise/. Scroll down to see problem.

Screenshot of the offending effect: [image: overlayproblem]

Can anyone give me any advice? I thought I may be able to fix it with a z-index but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `z-index: 2;` to `#footerwidth`

EDIT:

same goes for `#headerwidth`

EDIT2:

per ThinkingStiff's suggestion, you may also consider replacing the margin-bottom attribute of the footer with a padding-bottom attribute.

Comment: +1 The OP can also change `margin-bottom` to `padding-bottom` on `#footerwidth` to block the image from being seen underneath it. No point in making my own answer, you can just add this to yours if you wish.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff hm... I tried it but it seemed to have no effect on how the gallery image appears over the footer.

Comment: Ooops. I meant *in addition* to what you did with the `z-index`. `z-index` keeps it on top, but when you scroll down there is a thin sliver of the image showing in the margin of the footer.